# Extend selection to next blank line in notepad++

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

I recently switched from Textpad to Notepad++. Overall, I have found N++ to generally be superior, but one of the few things I have been looking for since the beginning that I have not found is the ability to extend the current selection to the next blank line.

In Textpad, this is done with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>down</kbd>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd> move up and down "paragraphs".

So <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd> will do what you want.

To edit the shortcut, go to *Settings > Shortcut Mapper > Scintilla Commands* and edit the SCI_PARA* commands.

Comment: Yes!  Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply `shift` + `up/down` without pressing `control`.

Comment: No, this only selects one line, regardless of whether it's blank or not.